# How to Fix Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError on Rails Project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

Rails Project Source code is below

```
def initialize_by_type(type, profile)
  @initializers ||= {
    "patient" => ->(x) { Interests::PatientNode.new(x) },
    "family" => ->(x) { Interests::FamilyNode.new(x) },
    "care_staff" => ->(x) { Interests::CareStaffNode.new(x) },
    "researcher" => ->(x) { Interests::ResearcherNode.new(x) },
    "doctor" => ->(x) { Interests::DoctorNode.new(x) },
    "medical_staff" => ->(x) { Interests::MedicalStaffNode.new(x) },
    "company" => ->(x) { Interests::CompanyNode.new(x) },
    "other" => ->(x) { Interests::OthersNode.new(x) }
  }
  initializer = @initializers[type]
  raise ArgumentError, "unexpected type: #{type}" unless initializer
  initializer.call(profile)
end
```

neo4j Errors is below

```
ERROR Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input ':' (line 1, column 20 (offset: 19))
"MATCH (n:Interests::ResearcherNode) RETURN n LIMIT 25"
^
```

I am working on Medical SNS Project, The Project is develop by ruby on rails and neo4j DB, I have some Problem on neo4j, How Can i fix this Problem?[Related Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36OxJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your cypher query is not correct.

You have this `(n:Interests::ResearcherNode)`, and for cypher it's correct. A `:` means the start of the label, or with `::` you are defining an empty label (this not allow).

So does your label is called `ResearcherNode` (1) or `:ResearcherNode` (2).

If (1) your query becomes :

```
MATCH (n:Interests:ResearcherNode) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

If (2), you need to surround your label name with back quotes :

```
MATCH (n:Interests:`:ResearcherNode`) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```